# What is the # in this post request for?

Tags: http, post

I'm using fiddler to observe a redirect request and the request looks like this:

https://example.com/api/dothis#code=123456&name=abcdef

I'm not familiar with what the hashtag (**#**) is for. Could I get an explanation?

Answer (score 0):

If it is an HTTP `POST` request to https://example.com/api/dothis#code=123456&name=abcdef, I think it is due to the backend (bad) design: The backend endpoint of `/api/dothis` will parse the string after `#` and extract the `code` and `name` parameter.

For the hashtag (`#`) itself, normally it is used to indicate anchor of HTML content, please refer to [Fragment Identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) for more information. According to the wikipedia's description, it is unlikely that `#code=123456&name=abcdef` works as fragment identifier.

`#` is also used in Single Page Application to navigate between application UIs. But it's not the case, as the HTTP method in this question is `POST`.